# error in 'QTR_NO_EMITTER_PIN' was not declared in this scope in arduino?

Tags: arduino

here is the part of code that i have problem in it, i add the library  and i include it, also it appear in (sketch-->import library)

```
#include <PololuQTRSensors.h>
    #include <Servo.h>

    // Change the values below to suit your robot's motors, weight, wheel type, etc.
    #define KP 0.5
    #define KD 1.7

#define M1_DEFAULT_SPEED 100
#define M2_DEFAULT_SPEED 100

#define rightMaxSpeed 200
#define leftMaxSpeed 200

#define NUM_SENSORS   6     // number of sensors used
#define TIMEOUT       2500  // waits for 2500 us for sensor outputs to go low

#define leftPWM   3    
#define rightPWM  5
//#define leftEnable 2
//#define rightEnable 4
//#define leftGND   2//12   //connected Directly to gnd 
//#define rightGND  4//13

#define echoPin 2 // Echo Pin
#define trigPin 4// Trigger Pin
#define LEDpin 13 //used for testing and calibration

#define DEBUG 0  
#define LINEFOLLOWER 0

Servo svoTilt;
Servo svoClaw;

/* Create instance of sensors. Sensors connected to pins 6 to 11
*/
PololuQTRSensorsRC qtrrc((unsigned char[]) {6,7,8,9,10,11},  NUM_SENSORS, TIMEOUT, QTR_NO_EMITTER_PIN);
```

but i have the following error in 'QTR_NO_EMITTER_PIN' was not declared in this scope,

i do not know why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to include the following in your sketch

```
#include <QTRSensors.h>
```

after your above the

```
#include <PololuQTRSensors.h>
#include <Servo.h>
```

---

After downloading the library, I was able to compile the following successfully.

```
#include <PololuQTRSensors.h>
#include <QTRSensors.h>
#include <Servo.h>
#define NUM_SENSORS   6     // number of sensors used
#define TIMEOUT       2500  // waits for 2500 us for sensor outputs to go low
#define DEBUG 0  
#define LINEFOLLOWER 0

Servo svoTilt;
Servo svoClaw;

QTRSensorsRC qtrrc((unsigned char[]) {6,7,8,9,10,11},  NUM_SENSORS, TIMEOUT, QTR_NO_EMITTER_PIN); 

void setup() {
  // put your setup code here, to run once:
}

void loop() {
  // put your main code here, to run repeatedly:
}
```

with the following successful result.

```
C:\Users\mflaga\AppData\Local\Temp\build5914291637870389663.tmp/QTR_NO_EMITTER_PIN.cpp.hex 

Sketch uses 2,264 bytes (7%) of program storage space. Maximum is 32,256 bytes.
Global variables use 84 bytes (4%) of dynamic memory, leaving 1,964 bytes for local variables. Maximum is 2,048 bytes.
```

Where I get the same error as reported above when I comment out the "#include "

Please note you may need to restart the IDE. to have it cache the presence of the library files.

Comment: how i can remove the library in arduino IDE?